# How to override internal framework method in application (outside framework)

Tags: swift, overriding, internal, subclassing, ios-charts

Is there anyway to override internal framework method when subclassing in Swift? 
Ex. 
Superclass

```
public class BarChartRenderer: ChartDataRendererBase {
   internal func drawDataSet(context context: CGContext, dataSet: BarChartDataSet, index: Int) {
             ...
   }
}
```

and I want to override this method to draw differently that dataSet (iOS-Charts)

```
public class ESBarChartRenderer: BarChartRenderer {
   overide func drawDataSet(context context: CGContext, dataSet: BarChartDataSet, index: Int) {
             ...
   }
}
```

but when I'm trying to override Xcode gives me error:

> Method does not override any method from its superclass

Because it's internal.

There is also one internal variable with I need access to and same as above Xcode can't see it.

Comment: have you figured it out?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `open` keyword instead of `public`

Check the the Access Control here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html