# How can I highlight the lowest data point in iOS-Charts?

Tags: ios, ios-charts

I would like to put an image that indicates this data point is the lowest point in the data. I made a picture to explain what I want. I am using BarChartView and RadarChartView.

[image]

### My trial

I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36929413/ios-charts-how-to-put-uiimage-beside-a-point) is similar to my question but I need to get position to put UIImage. If I know the position, I can do it or do `addSubview`. `getMarkerPosition` function looks useful to determine the right position.

Also, `ChartMarker` looks helpful. In the `ChartsDemo` some chart views are using `BalloonMarker`. It is almost what I want to do. Here is a quote from `RadarChartViewController.m`.

```
BalloonMarker *marker = [[BalloonMarker alloc] initWithColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:180/255. alpha:1.0] font:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0] insets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(8.0, 8.0, 20.0, 8.0)];
marker.minimumSize = CGSizeMake(80.f, 40.f);
_chartView.marker = marker;
```

BalloonMarker is created and added to `_chartView.marker`. Therefore, a marker comes up when an user clicks on a bar but I want to show a marker always. In other words, the library decides the right time to show and hide a marker . I couldn't find the way to pop up a marker actively.

I would be grateful if you could tell me the way to do this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `BarChartRenderer` class you can find method

> public override func drawValues(context context: CGContext)

inside body of `if (!dataSet.isStacked)` in the for-loop you can first define the minimum value using `e.value` and corresponding `valuePoint` variable, so after loop you will have coordinates where the minimum value will be drawn and adding some offset you can draw also your marker

```
let image = UIImage(named: "MARKER")
image?.drawInRect(CGRect(x: valuePoint.x, y: SOME_OFFSET + valuePoint.y + (val >= 0.0 ? posOffset : negOffset), width: 16, height: 16))
```

Or in

> public func drawDataSet(context context: CGContext, dataSet:
>   IBarChartDataSet, index: Int)

You can find `barRect` of the smallest bar and play with that results.

Comment: Thank you keyv, I am going to resolve the question. I have added some code in the func `drawValues`, and I got a success. By the way, I I don't want to modify the file because the file belongs to the iOS chart library. Probably, I have to make subclasses of `BarChartView` and `BarChartRenderer`; however because these methods are internal, I cannot override them. I found a similar question to my situation that Mateusz posted 4 months ago and no one answered it. Would you be able to tell me what should I do next? Anyway, I appreciate your kind answer. Thank you again.

Comment: The post I mentioned above is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35033301/how-to-override-internal-framework-method-in-application-outside-framework).

Comment: I can't see any other variant than modifying those library files, unfortunately.

Comment: OK, I appreciate it. If I can resolve the issue, I will post it here.